# Error 405 en FullCalendar Laravel

Tags: laravel, fullcalendar

tengo un error que me lanza la consola de chrome, y no me deja enviar el formulario a la base de datos, el error es este, gracias:

> POST http://localhost:8000/todo-eve 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Nose que puede ser, he visto muchos posts y niuno me lo soluciona o me da alguna idea clara, espero me puedan ayudar con este problema, les envio codigo e imagen, para que puedan visualizar mejor la situacion, desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

AJAX

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "{{route('calendario')}}",
  data: formData,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  async: false,
  success: function(feedback) {

    var jd = $.parseJSON(feedback);

    if (jd.type == 'alert-success') {
      $("#create_event_frm")[0].reset();
      $('#create_event_modal').modal('hide');
      $('#create_event_alert').show().html('');


      $('#alert_tmeassage_area').show().html('<div class="alert ' + jd.type + '"><a href="" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>' + jd.message + '</div>');
      reloadCalender();
    } else {


      var msg = '';

      $.each(jd.error, function(key, value) {
        msg += value + '</br>';
      });

      $('#create_event_alert').show().html('<div class="alert ' + jd.type + '"><a href="" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>' + msg + '</div>');


    }

  }


});
```

```js
public
function guardar_evento(Request $request) {

  $validator = Validator::make($request - > all(), [
    'event_title' => 'required|string|max:150',
    'event_start_date' => 'required|string|max:15',
  ]);


  $feed_back = array();
  if ($validator - > passes()) {

    if ($request['set_end_date_data'] == "No") {
      $request['event_end_date'] = $request['event_start_date'];
    }
    $request['event_start_date'] = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $request['event_start_date'])));
    $request['event_end_date'] = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $request['event_end_date'])));
    Event::create($request - > all());

    $feed_back['type'] = 'alert-success';
    $feed_back['message'] = 'Added new records';
    $feed_back['error'] = array();

  } else {
    $feed_back['type'] = 'alert-danger';
    $feed_back['error'] = $validator - > errors() - > all();

  }

  return json_encode($feed_back);
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('calendario','calendarController@viewCalendar')->name('calendario');
    Route::get('listCalendario', 'calendarController@viewListc');
    Route::post('calendario','calendarController@guardar_evento');
    Route::get('todo-eve','calendarController@todo_evento')->name('todo-eve');
    Route::get('simple-eve/{id}','calendarController@simple_evento');
    Route::post('actualizar-eve','calendarController@actualizar_evento');
    Route::delete('borrar-eve/{id}','calendarController@borrar_evento');
```

Comment: Puedes agregar a tu pregunta tu routes o resource para **todo-eve** por favor?

Comment: no pude editar la pregunta, pero te las envio por aqui

Comment: Route::get('calendario', 'calendarController@viewCalendar')->name('calendario');
Route::get('listCalendario', 'calendarController@viewListc');
 
Route::post('calendario','calendarController@guardar_evento');

Route::get('todo-eve','calendarController@todo_evento')->name('todo-eve');


Route::get('simple-eve/{id}','calendarController@simple_evento');
Route::post('actualizar-eve','calendarController@actualizar_evento');
Route::delete('borrar-eve/{id}','calendarController@borrar_evento');

Answer (score 0):

Estoy casi seguro que tu error está en tu routes, en esta línea:

> Route::get('todo-eve','calendarController@todo_evento')->name('todo-eve');

Tienes definida la ruta /todo-eve como un **GET**. Tú le estás mandando un **POST**. Entonces, o cambias el get del route por un post o le envías un get desde tu petición. Revisa las secciones:

Solución 1)

```
 Route::get('todo-eve','calendarController@todo_evento')->name('todo-eve');
```

por

```
 Route::post('todo-eve','calendarController@todo_evento')->name('todo-eve');
```

Solución 2)

> $.ajax({   type: 'POST',...

por

> $.ajax({   type: 'GET',...

Comment: eso fue lo primero que pense, pero cuando reviso el codigo del calendario original (que se instala por composer) este tiene la misma ruta que tengo yo, y le genera bien todo :c

Comment: A ver, veo en el código que agregaste a tu pregunta que citas una función **guardar_evento** que está ruteada al recurso /calendario. entonces, no tendrías que consumir el recurso (la url) **/calendario** en lugar de **/todo-even**? porque /calendario sí espera un **POST**

Comment: si amigo, eso me di cuenta y lo cambie recien modifico la pregunta ahora el error que me aparece es POST 500 D:

Answer (score 0):

La ruta que pones en ajax `route('calendario')` corresponde con esta:

```
Route::get('calendario','calendarController@viewCalendar')->name('calendario');
```

Si quieres llegar al método del controlador que muestras en la pregunta, dale un nombre a la ruta correspondiente:

```
Route::post('calendario','calendarController@guardar_evento')->name('guardar-evento');
```

Una vez que hayas asignado un nombre a la ruta, podrás usarlo para generar direcciones URL a través del helper [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-route).
Entonces en ajax:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "{{route('guardar-evento')}}",
```

O si en cambio, quieres usar la `uri` de la ruta y no el nombre. Utiliza el helper [`url()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-url);

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "{{url('calendario')}}",
```